# Trying deploy war on Tomcat 7 taken from a GWT-RPC project

Tags: tomcat, gwt, war, gwt-rpc

I have my GWT-RPC project, that use on server the SDK merchant of paypal (for Express Checkout) that use the following classpath:

```
<classpath>
            <pathelement location="/home/anto0192/Documenti/TesiProvaFinale/TesiFinale/MovieUniverseFinal/src" />
            <pathelement location="/home/anto0192/Documenti/TesiProvaFinale/TesiFinale/MovieUniverseFinal/war/WEB-INF/classes" />
            <pathelement location="/media/Dati/Uni(IIIanno)/Tesi/postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc4.jar" />
            <pathelement location="/home/anto0192/Documenti/TesiProvaFinale/paypal-core-1.4.3.jar" />
            <pathelement location="/home/anto0192/Documenti/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar" />
            <pathelement location="/home/anto0192/Documenti/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-dev.jar" />
            <pathelement location="/home/anto0192/Documenti/gwt-2.7.0/validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar" />
            <pathelement location="/home/anto0192/Documenti/gwt-2.7.0/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar" />
            <pathelement location="/home/anto0192/Documenti/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-codeserver.jar" />
            <pathelement location="/home/anto0192/Documenti/TesiProvaFinale/merchant-sdk-java-2.13.117/merchantsdk/target/merchantsdk-2.13.117.jar" />
            <pathelement location="/home/anto0192/Documenti/TesiProvaFinale/merchant-sdk-java-2.13.117/merchantsdk/target/merchantsdk-2.13.117-javadoc.jar" />
            <pathelement location="/home/anto0192/Documenti/TesiProvaFinale/merchant-sdk-java-2.13.117/merchantsdk/target/merchantsdk-2.13.117-sources.jar" />
            <pathelement location="/home/anto0192/Documenti/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-dev.jar" />
        </classpath>
```

On my war/WEB-INF/lib I have added

```
gwt-codeserver.jar  gwt-servlet.jar           paypal-core-1.4.3.jar
gwt-dev.jar         merchantsdk-2.13.117.jar  postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc4.jar
```

I generate the war from the direcory war containing

```
MovieUniverse  MovieUniverse.html  WEB-INF
```

with the terminal command:

```
sudo jar -cvf MovieUniverse.war MovieUniverse.html WEB-INF;
```

I deploy from manager app of Tomcat.
The deploy happen and I can see it in my list of Tomcat app.
I go on the page

```
http://localhost:8080/MovieUniverse/MovieUniverse.html
```

I receive on the console of chrome this error:

```
 http://localhost:8080/MovieUniverse/MovieUniverse/MovieUniverse.nocache.js 404 (Not Found)
```

The page isn't loaded, what can i do? I think it's a problem with the jar inserted in WEB-INF/lib, but I cannot reach to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

For the future: I reach it, with the command line:

```
sudo jar -cvf MovieUniverse.war *
```

from inside the war path